# pgfplots: How to draw a line to the end of the coordinate system

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image]

How can I draw a vertical line exactly to end of the coordinate system in y-direction?

· *Note that the (automatically setted) 'ymax=10' can change (and I do not know `ymax=<value>`, because the tables contains randomized numbers.)*

· *Note that the x-value '6' is given (normally read out from the table as a special value).*

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
0, 0
1, 0
2, 0
3, 1
4, 3
5, 2
6, 5
7, 0
8, 1
12,10
13,5
}\mytable


\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, ymin=0, 
]
\addplot[mark=*] table[]{\mytable};

\addplot[densely dashed, red] coordinates{(6,0) (6,10)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also `[enlarge y limits=false].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
0, 0
1, 0
2, 0
3, 1
4, 3
5, 2
6, 5
7, 0
8, 1
12,10
13,5
}\mytable
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, ymin=0, 
]
\addplot[mark=*] table[]{\mytable};
\draw[red, ultra thick, densely dashed] (6,0) -- (6,0|-current axis.north);
\draw[green, densely dashed] (6,0) -- (6,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's elegant too. TYVM.

Answer (score 5):

Two ideas (you should set the `compat` option to a recent eversion in any case):

1. Make use of `update limits=false` to prevent the coordinates of the line to extend the y axis limits:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
0, 0
1, 0
2, 0
3, 1
4, 3
5, 2
6, 5
7, 0
8, 1
12,10
13,5
}\mytable

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0, ymin=0, 
]
\addplot[mark=*] table[]{\mytable};

\addplot[densely dashed, red, update limits=false] coordinates{(6,0) (6,11)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

2. Draw the line using a `\draw` command:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
0, 0
1, 0
2, 0
3, 1
4, 3
5, 2
6, 5
7, 0
8, 1
12,10
13,5
}\mytable

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0, ymin=0
]
\addplot[mark=*] table[]{\mytable};

\draw[densely dashed, red] 
    (6,0 |- {yticklabel cs:0}) -- (6,0 |- {yticklabel cs:1});

% alternatively:
% \draw[densely dashed, red] 
%    (6,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (6,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both code examples yield the same output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's elegant. TYVM.

Comment: Also `(rel axis cs: 0,0)` and `(rel axis cs: 1,1)` to locate the top and bottom.